# Javascript - Populando um campo com parágrafo

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, vb.net

Estou elaborando um javascript para popular uma caixa de texto, porém me deparei com uma situação que está me gerando dificuldade. Preciso popular com essa mensagem por exemplo:

TESTE

TESTE

TESTE

Porém não estou conseguindo trazer as quebras de linha quando populo o campo, tentei com `/n,<br>, </ br>, vbCrLf`, porém não obtive êxito. Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Ressaltando que minha caixa de texto em html está assim:

```
<td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="teste" class="CaixaTexto" runat="server" style="width: 600px;
                height: 90px;" cols="97" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
```

Att,

Comment: Tentou `\n\r`? Ou mesmo só `\n`?

Comment: Tentei o `\n\r` e deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />')`, exemplo:

```js
  var txtBox = $('textarea');
txtBox.keydown(function(e){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        var html = that.value.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>");
        $("div").html(html);
    },10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você disse que testou `/n`, quando na verdade deveria ser `\n` ou `\n\r`.

Comment: Correto.. Agora testei o '\n\r', porém meu java script não está populando após a primeira quebra. Ficando desta forma: